# Applying Lusin's theorem to a Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a real valued function that is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\varepsilon >0$. Show that there is a continuous function $g$ that is identically zero outside some interval and such that $$\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} |f-g| <\varepsilon.$$ (Hint: Lusin's theorem}

So I used Lusin's theorem and a function $g$ appears from Lusin's but I don't know how this function will satisfy the conclusion of the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the proof is giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm having trouble showing that $g$ is identically zero outside some interval. i don't know how to get the interval from the closed set $F$ obtained from Lusin's. At the same time when I integrate $|f-g|$ over $\mathbb{R}\setminus F$, I don't know how to make this less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Do you have any other theorems at your disposal? Specifically about how $L^1$ functions decay at $\pm \infty$ ? Or maybe about how we may approximate $L^1$ functions with simple functions?

Comment: If you know that step functions are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, you could approximate the characteristic function of an interval by a continuous function of compact support (which is much easier to do).

Comment: Can you tell us which version of Lusin's Theorem was given in your lecture? The version I am familiar with is unlikely to help (without the help of other results), since it "only" gives a closed set $C$ such that $\lambda(\Bbb R\setminus C)<\epsilon$ and $f|_C$ is continuous - but it says nothing about what happens outside of $C$. Even if we extend $f|_C$ to a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ (via [Tietze's Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem)), I keep running into this problem.

Comment: That is the same version of Lusin's theorem that we have.